# Search for exact term in an Algolia index

Tags: search, exact-match, algolia

I want to filter an index by an exact value of an attribute. I wonder what possibilities Algolia offers for that.

Querying an index always results in a search for substrings, that means a search term `abc` will always match any object which attribute values contain `abc`.  What I want to achieve is a search for `abc` that finds only `abc` as a value of an attribute (in this case I have specific attributes to search in).

One possibility I came up with was tagging, which doesn't seem to be the best way to think of.

**Edit**

I think I could also use facet filters.  I thought about the different pros and cons and can't come up with arguments that places either one position above the other.

Answer (score 4):

You're right with your edit that facet filters would be the way to go on this one. You'll get the exact match you're looking for and won't have to create a new attribute of `_tags` to use the tag filter.